# ggballonplot set limits for axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

To make the plots more comparable, I would like to set the limits of all fill- and symbol size axes to the same size. Is this possible? Also the legends for "size" and "fill" are swapping places in the last two plots, which I would like to prevent as well.
Thanks in advance!!!

### ggballonplot chart

[image: See link...]

### Some code as an example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plot4 <- ggballoonplot(data_matrix_comb, x = "Time", y = "Depth", 
         size = "mean_percentage_of_indivuals",
         fill = "mean_variance", facet.by = "Stage",
         ggtheme = theme_bw()) + scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C") + 
         labs(title "Autumn")

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol=2, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ggarrange()` from `ggpubr()`,I would suggest a common legend since it doesn't make sense to have it 4 times.

I simulated some data since you did not provide (please do so in the future!).

Also slight variation from what you did, I placed all the data.frames inside a list, and if possible, you should try that so that you don't run the same code multiple times.. (i.e avoid copy-paste code):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(111)
dat = data.frame(Time=rep(c("day","night"),12),
          Depth=rep(c("aphotic","euphotic"),each=2,times=6),
          Stage = rep(c("adult","juvenil"),each=4),
          mean_percentage_of_indivuals=100*runif(24),
          mean_variance = rnbinom(24,mu=100,size=0.5))

dat_all = dat %>% group_by(Time,Depth,Stage) %>% summarize_all(mean)
dat_spring = dat[1:8,]
dat_summer = dat[9:16,]
dat_autumn = dat[17:24,]

dat_list = list("All Seasons"=dat_all,"Spring"=dat_spring,
                "Summer"=dat_summer,"Autumn"=dat_autumn)

plts = lapply(names(dat_list),function(i){

         p <- ggballoonplot(dat_list[[i]], x = "Time", y = "Depth", 
         size = "mean_percentage_of_indivuals",
         fill = "mean_variance", facet.by = "Stage",
         ggtheme = theme_bw()) + 
         scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C") + 
         labs(title=i)
         
         return(p)
})

ggarrange(plotlist =plts,ncol=2, nrow=2, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time, I really appreciate your help! Thats just what I needed. And yes, I'll provide the data next time :)